# Nss-pam-ldapd host based login with TLS

Tags: ldap, tls

I have an openldap server configured and set up for linux client logins with host based authentications. All is fine except I wanted to have TLS and have found that it is not working de to a bug https://www.gc3.uzh.ch/blog/Fixing_LDAP_Authentication_over_TLS/

I read that I should be using this http://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/setup instead. I got stuck at how to set up host based authentication that I had working with the old way: in ldap.conf:

```
ubuntu LDAPClientAuthentication, the 3rd way nss_based nss_base_passwd 

ou=users,dc=valami,dc=valami?one?|(host=client23)(host=*) nss_base_shadow 

ou=users,dc=valami,dc=valami?one?|(host=client23)(host=*) nss_base_group 

ou=group,dc=valami,dc=valami?one sudoers_base ou=SUDOers,dc=valami,dc=valami
```

now with `nslcd.conf`. I do not know how to do it? Can you recommend a way or have anyone done it?